# Unable to access website admin page - 500 error - how to change landing page

Tags: login, 500-internal-error

Help is required to solve a problem created by a stupid mistake.

Our website is hosted by Godaddy and created with Wordpress. It had been set up and running smoothly for long.

Recently We wanted to keep the website down for some time as we wanted to modify some contents. So with a "brilliant-idea-moment", using wp-admin login, in the dashboard, the landing page name was changed from "mydomain.com" to "mydomain.com/404".

Now we are not able to access the wp-admin login page at all to revert back, as it keeps redirecting it to "mydomain.com/404/wp-admin", a page which does not exist so giving a 500 error message.

Is there anyway, we could change the landing page back to original, through hosting admin or cPanel by editing any specific file?

Your assistance would be highly helpful.

Comment: to set the good URL, try this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#If_You_Have_Accidentally_Changed_your_WordPress_Site_URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to you Cpanel through godaddy and search for `PHPMyadmin`. The interface that allow you to manage your database.

Then search for a table called `wp_options` then in this table you should be able to find the url of the site in two places (**siteurl**,**home**) and you should be able to change it back to the domain name.

After this you will be able to access the admin again, then you should go to the permalinks settings and hit save (without doing any changes). This will correct your url rewriting.

Comment: On following the suggested changes, now I am able to get the site loading correctly and able to access the admin page well.

However but for the home page, other pages are still showing 500 error. Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks for the timely help.

Comment: after doing this, go to the permalinks setting in the dashboard and click save, maybe it will solve the issue

Comment: Yes. that did, in fact, solve the issue.  Thanks a ton

Comment: great, am gonna add it to the answer so it's complete ;) and you can mark it as accepted then